# bokeh: erratic behaviour of empty canvas, with pretty much identical data

Tags: canvas, line, draw, bokeh

I have a curious problem with bokeh for visualizing lines from data. I extracted the data giving the problem and narrowed it down to the following example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

fig = figure(width=1200, height=300, x_axis_type="datetime")

fig.line(x=['1511550670', '1511550995', '1511551093', '1511551108'],
         y=[-99.99994912, -99.99995743, -99.99995395, -99.99995494],
         color='blue', legend='no line?')

fig.line(x=['1511550670', '1511550995', '1511551093', '1511551108'],
         y=[-0.16839438, -0.04496412, 0.14891187, 0.12161594],
         color='red', legend='line!')

output_file("overall.html")

show(fig)
```

Both datasets seem perfectly fine to me, yet only one is printed in the canvas.
Can anyone help me out with what the frog is going on here?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that usage of providing timestamps as strings works in some use cases, it is purely unintentional and accidental. It is not documented anywhere, or supported. Passing actual numeric timestamps works as expected:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

fig = figure(width=1200, height=300, x_axis_type="datetime")

fig.line(x=[1511550670, 1511550995, 1511551093, 1511551108],
         y=[-99.99994912, -99.99995743, -99.99995395, -99.99995494],
         color='blue', legend='no line?')

fig.line(x=[1511550670, 1511550995, 1511551093, 1511551108],
         y=[-0.16839438, -0.04496412, 0.14891187, 0.12161594],
         color='red', legend='line!')

output_file("overall.html")

show(fig)
```

[image]

In addition to raw timestamps as above, any typical datetime values from python, pandas, numpy etc. will also work.